# FBA with LDAP on SharePoint 2013 Standard not working

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have followed the below article but I am not able to get the FBA working.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spblog/archive/2014/09/26/configure-a-sharepoint-2013-web-application-with-forms-based-authentication-with-a-ldap-membership-provider.aspx

I cannot see Forms Auth users when I am adding user policy to my web application, also when I am going to IIS and selecting .Net User or .Net Roles I am seeing the following error

> You can use this feature only when the default provider is the trusted provider

I dont know if the above error could be because of the configuration changes that I have made.

Answer (score 0):

The server name wasn't correct. Its now working.